# How to convert sqllite date time into localtime via moor select api

Tags: sqlite, flutter, flutter-moor

I am building a mobile application using flutter and moor as database library. I have to fetch all transactions for a particular month. My query is like below.

```
Future<List<Transaction>> fetchTransactionsByCategory(
  String name, DateTime reportDate) {
  return (select(transactions)
      ..where((i) {
        final date = i.date;
        return date.year.equals(reportDate.year) &
            date.month.equals(reportDate.month) &
            i.subCategory.equals(name);
      }))
    .get();
```

}

The issue is if the transaction time is May 01, 2021 12:00:00 AM, it is not coming under May report, instead it is coming under April report. I am able to understand in the database it is getting persisted as 30 Apr 2021 16:00:00 PM (timezone +8 here).

How I have to write the query to fetch the transactions based on local time zone? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In your pubspec `intl: ^0.16.1`
and import

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

in your highest state(First state).

and then you can use it like ;

```
@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 initializeDateFormatting();
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to explain? I don't get it. The issue is at query level.